# What is the recommended approach to keep failed records in Google Data Flow pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Want to keep the failed records in a Google Dataflow pipeline so that it can be searched / retried later. What is the best component to keep the failed records? The records need to be stored customer wise and date wise (for each day). Is Pub/Sub or Bigquery or Datastore appropriate for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a generalized solution for this in Beam. Each sink may offer their own way of capturing and handling failed records. For example, [BigQuery sink](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) offers getFailedInserts() function that will allow your to obtain a PCollection of failed records when writing to BigQuery using streaming inserts. If you are writing from a custom ParDo transform, you can implement a similar feature by outputting failed elements from your ParDo.